# Eraser tool in Paint using GP142 using C++

Tags: visual-c++

I am using of **GP142*** in paint by `c++` and had made Bucket tool, colored shapes, etc. but i am facing major problem regarding **ERASER TOOL**. I'd very thankful if you will help me a bit.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I am not being able to write a code to erase two shapes drawn through GP142 on C++